# Add ability to sort by flag status in profile

Tags: feature-request, flags

Currently, the only way to determine the status of a flag is to look at your flagging history in your profile. This is a time consuming process, as the flags are ordered by the time the flag was issued. If you wish to see only flags that have been disputed or declined, you need to go through multiple pages of flags.

In the UI, I propose making the information the right, in the flagging history, links that filters the flags to the appropriate flags.

By making these two options links, I could quickly see which flags were declined or disputed.

[image: Make links?]

Comment: This will help me quickly find my rarely declined flags, instead of browsing through the individual pages.