# Where can I find my flag history, number of profile views, and review history while using the Stack Exchange Android App?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page, android-app, flag-history

I'm using the Stack Exchange Android App and I didn't find a way to see my number of profile views, flag history, or review history in my profile page. Where can I see those details in the Android app?

Answer (score 5):

The Android-app and iOS-app use the [Stack API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) .

Flag history and review history is not exposed in version 2.2 of the API.

That means there is no way to get that info at the moment.

`view_count` is in the [user](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) type if you call [/me][2] so it could made available but isn't at the moment as shown by the screenshot from [Unihedrons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3622940/unihedron) device

[image: unihedrons profile]

<sup>the use of the image is granted [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/24908073#24908073)</sup>

There is a feature request to add the [flag status/history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245416/add-ability-to-get-flag-status-via-api) to the API.

[2]: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me#order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=!)scV0QzslTyHKs4_6eqx&site=stackoverflow&run=true

Comment: Related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245416/add-ability-to-get-flag-status-via-api