# Can we have the ability to retract a flag on a deleted post?

Tags: feature-request, flags, deleted-questions, retracted-flags

Can we introduce a way to retract a flag on a deleted post or comment, or on *any* post, from the "Flags Raised" page?  Right now, you have to go to the post to retract your flag, but it might be deleted.  A few times I've raised valid flags on an abusive comment or a troll's post, only to receive the message:

> Declined - A moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it.

or to see that my flag is still pending, but the offensive post is gone.  Ten thousand reputation is a lot just to have this simple feature, and being able to do this would also save the moderator time to review the flag.  Does anybody else see this as a good feature?

Comment: This has already been requested: [Allow retracting a moderator flag if the post has been deleted and I don't have enough reputation to see deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307382/allow-retracting-a-moderator-flag-if-the-post-has-been-deleted-and-i-dont-have)