# Cancelling flags doesn't work from the Android app

Tags: support, flags, android-app

In [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87500/295232), the feature of canceling flags is explained. 
But I don't find a retract flag button after flagging a question or answer. As I'm using the Android app, I'm wondering if this is only implemented in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if this is only implemented in browser.

Correct, you can't *retract* (the official name for cancel) flags. The reason for this is that it isn't possible via the API, though there is a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288120/295232) to enable it. As the Android app uses the Stack Exchange API, your only option is to open the post in a browser and retract it from there.